# Ошибка 'Reverse accessor' при выполнении миграции в Django

Tags: python, django-model

Есть абстрактный класс:

```
    class Items(models.Model):
        id_index = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        id_client = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
        id_icon = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        ability_1 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        ability_2 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        ability_3 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        ability_4 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

        class Meta:
            abstract=True
```

И классы зависящие от него (для примера 2, но их много около 20, в них указывается имя таблицы и могут быть доп. поля)

```
    class UpperItem(Items):

        class Meta:
            managed = True
            db_table = 'UpperItem'

    class LowerItem(Items):

        class Meta:
            managed = True
            db_table = 'LowerItem'
```

Есть класс с умениями:

```
    class ItemAbilities(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
        name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        note = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

        class Meta:
            managed = True
            db_table = 'item_abilities'
```

При изменении(нужно 4 поля, но для примера 2) на

```
    ability_1 = models.ManyToManyField(ItemAbilities)
    ability_2 = models.ManyToManyField(ItemAbilities)
```

И выполнении `makemigration` возникает ошибка:

> app_test.UpperItem.ability_1: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'app_test.UpperItem.ability_1' clashes with reverse accessor for 'app_test.UpperItem.ability_2'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app_test.UpperItem.ability_1' or 'app_test.UpperItem.ability_2'.
> app_test.UpperItem.ability_2: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'app_test.UpperItem.ability_2' clashes with reverse accessor for 'app_test.UpperItem.ability_1'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app_test.UpperItem.ability_2' or 'app_test.UpperItem.ability_1'.
> app_test.LowerItem.ability_1: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'app_test.LowerItem.ability_1' clashes with reverse accessor for 'app_test.LowerItem.ability_2'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app_test.LowerItem.ability_1' or 'app_test.LowerItem.ability_2'.
> app_test.LowerItem.ability_2: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'app_test.LowerItem.ability_2' clashes with reverse accessor for 'app_test.LowerItem.ability_1'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app_test.LowerItem.ability_2' or 'app_test.LowerItem.ability_1'.

Если прописать related_name поля одной таблицы начинают конфликтовать с полями других таблиц

```
    ability_1 = models.ManyToManyField(info_ItemAbilities, related_name='ability_01')
    ability_2 = models.ManyToManyField(info_ItemAbilities, related_name='ability_02')
```

> app_test.AmuletItem.ability_1: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'app_test.AmuletItem.ability_1' clashes with reverse accessor for 'app_test.CloakItem.ability_1'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app_test.AmuletItem.ability_1' or 'app_test.CloakItem.ability_1'.
> app_test.AmuletItem.ability_1: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'app_test.AmuletItem.ability_1' clashes with reverse accessor for 'app_test.GauntletItem.ability_1'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app_test.AmuletItem.ability_1' or 'app_test.GauntletItem.ability_1'.
> app_test.AmuletItem.ability_1: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'app_test.AmuletItem.ability_1' clashes with reverse accessor for 'app_test.HelmetItem.ability_1'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app_test.AmuletItem.ability_1' or 'app_test.HelmetItem.ability_1'.
> app_test.AmuletItem.ability_1: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'app_test.AmuletItem.ability_1' clashes with reverse accessor for 'app_test.LowerItem.ability_1'.

Итоговая цель всего, мне нужно обращаться к `name` (или другим полям) модели `ItemAbilities` через `LoweItem`, `UpperItem` и другие `...Item`.